# Plotting from pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Given the following `pandas` data frame, named `work`  (the time column is the index)

```
    time    username    counter
    9.0     Person.A        5
    10.0    Person.A        4
    11.0    Person.A        5
    11.0    Person.B        3
    11.0    Person.C        5
    12.0    Person.A        3
    12.0    Person.B        5
    12.0    Person.C        2
```

how to produce a bar plotting such as
[image]

using `matplotlib`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html), but need reshape data first by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) or [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df.set_index(['time','username'])['counter'].unstack(fill_value=0).plot.bar()
```

Or:

```
df.pivot(index='time',columns='username', values='counter').plot.bar()
```

If first or second solution does not work, because duplicates in pairs `time` and `username` is necessary aggregation in `groupby` + aggregate function or [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df.groupby(['time','username'])['counter'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0).plot.bar()

df.pivot_table(index='time',columns='username', values='counter', aggfunc='sum').plot.bar()
```